# C# can I start a thread and use a dispatcher to schedule work on it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dispatcher

I'd like to have a dedicated thread I can schedule work on. Can I do this using dispatcher.invoke or do I have to do something custom?

It seems like dispatcher should work, but I can't figure out how to actually get the thread to start processing work from the dispatcher.

Answer (score 5):

The only problem I see is how to tell when the thread's dispatcher is up and running, and ready to accept commands. I added a `Thread.Sleep(100)` for this reason. Without it a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} Started");
    Dispatcher.Run();
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} Finished");
});
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Name = "Worker";
thread.Start();
Thread.Sleep(100);
Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(thread);
dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processed by {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
});
dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
thread.Join();
```

Output:

> Worker Started
>   Processed by Worker
>   Worker Finished

---

**Update:** A custom dispatcher could be implemented using a [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1). The class below has many missing features (cancellation, timeout, arguments, dispose etc), but offer the important advantage that can be shared by multiple worker threads.

```
public class CustomDispatcher
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<(Action Action,
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> TCS)> _blockingCollection =
        new BlockingCollection<(Action, TaskCompletionSource<bool>)>();

    public void Run()
    {
        foreach (var item in _blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            try
            {
                item.Action.Invoke();
                item.TCS.SetResult(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                item.TCS.TrySetException(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(Action action)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        _blockingCollection.Add((action, tcs));
        return tcs.Task;
    }

    public void Invoke(Action action) => InvokeAsync(action).Wait();

    public void InvokeShutdown() => _blockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
}
```

---

**Update:** Regarding the build-in [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher), instead of using the messy `Thread.Sleep(100)` to give time to the dispatcher to start, a `TaskCompletionSource<Dispatcher>` could be used for precise control:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Main";
var dispatcherReady = new TaskCompletionSource<Dispatcher>();
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} Started");
    dispatcherReady.SetResult(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
    Dispatcher.Run();
    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name} Finished");
});
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Name = "Worker";
thread.Start();
var dispatcher = dispatcherReady.Task.Result;
dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Processed by {Thread.CurrentThread.Name}");
});
dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
thread.Join();
```

Output:

> Worker Started
>   Processed by Worker
>   Worker Finished

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are using C# and UWP or something similar.

You cannot (or a at least not easily) reserve a thread and dispatch tasks onto it. In current Windows environments, tasks are run on **synchronization contexts**. In practical terms this means a set of threads that is either (a) in the UI synchronization context the set of threads contains just the one UI thread, or (b) in the thread pool synchronization context there is a collection of worker threads.

In most cases if you are trying to do CPU-intensive work then you should be running it on the thread pool, which you do by calling `Task.Run( asyncAction)`. To get the results back onto the UI you have to use `Dispatcher.RunAsync`. You also can use the dispatcher from the UI thread if you want to return from your method first and have something executed in the UI thread later.

What you should not do is use the Dispatcher to schedule background work. All the work scheduled using the Dispatcher will be run on the single UI thread, causing it to bog down.

Answer (score 0):

Call [Dispatcher.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.run?view=netframework-4.8). This will block the thread, the dispatcher will run an endless loop waiting for messages and processing them.

Before doing that, it's a good idea to store the instance of the dispatcher somewhere, where other threads can access it to post messages or shutdown.

The downside is, you'll have to only use the dispatcher to post work for that thread. It won't do anything else. Call InvokeShutdown to stop.